# How to fix RSpec test that depends on time passing by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following method in one of my controlllers:

```
def ping
  @obj.last_ping_at = DateTime.now
  @obj.save!
end
```

I would like to test that this is working, so I wrote the following test:

```
it 'successfully updates last_ping_at' do
  old_last_ping_at = obj.last_ping_at
  patch url(obj)
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
  expect(obj.reload.last_ping_at).not_to eql(old_last_ping_at)
end
```

Here is the problem: the time IS always the same. The only way it changes it's if I add a `binding.pry` to the controller method and then continue.

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/684) discussion help you out at all?

Answer (score 1):

Set `last_ping_at` to something definitely not now, then check if it's close to now with [`be_within`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher).

```
it 'successfully updates last_ping_at' do
  obj.update!(last_ping_at: 1.day.ago)

  patch url(obj)

  expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
  expect(obj.reload.last_ping_at).to be_within(1.second).of(DateTime.now)
end
```

---

Note: `DateTime.now` will be the time zone on your machine, not the application's time zone. Use `DateTime.current` instead.

```
[4] pry(main)> Time.zone = "Fiji"
=> "Fiji"
[5] pry(main)> DateTime.now
=> Thu, 21 Jan 2021 12:13:14 -0800
[6] pry(main)> DateTime.current
=> Fri, 22 Jan 2021 08:13:16 +1200
[7] pry(main)>
```

See [It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones).

---

Sometimes you can't use `be_within`. In that case you can freeze time. For general Ruby [use timecop as @max says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834806/14660). Rails has that built in with [`travel_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to).

```
it 'successfully updates last_ping_at' do
  travel_to Time.current do
    patch url(obj)

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    expect(obj.reload.last_ping_at).to eq Time.current
  end
end
```

I go a step further and bake this into rspec metadata.

```
# spec/support/config/travel_to.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around do |example|
    if example.metadata[:travel_to]
      travel_to example.metadata[:travel_to] do
        example.run
      end
    else
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can `travel_to: Time.current` in any RSpec block.

```
it 'successfully updates last_ping_at', travel_to: Time.current do
  patch url(obj)

  expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
  expect(obj.reload.last_ping_at).to eq Time.current
end
```

YMMV whether you prefer the explicit block or the implicit metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `travel` method:

```
it 'successfully updates last_ping_at' do
  old_last_ping_at = obj.last_ping_at

  travel 1.day do
    patch url(obj)
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    expect(obj.reload.last_ping_at).not_to eql(old_last_ping_at)
  end
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel